# Getting url and HTMl through a BHO, SetSite throws an exception

Tags: c#, com, interop, bho

I have followed the tutorial at: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040331.htm for making a BHO, however i doesnt seem to work for me, i have the Observer code from the examble, where she creates the actual BHO, but when i try to typecast in my SetSite it stops, i suspect i get an exception.

This is my sample code, just stripped it all bare, so i get a messagebox instead.

```
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [GuidAttribute("0CD00297-9A19-4698-AEF1-682FBE9FE88D")]
    [ProgIdAttribute("Observer.BrowserMonitor")]
    public class BrowserMonitor: IObserver, IObjectWithSite
    {

        // HRESULT values used
        const int E_FAIL = unchecked((int)0x80004005);
        const int E_NOINTERFACE = unchecked((int)0x80004002);

        public BrowserMonitor()
        {

        }


        protected SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 m_pIWebBrowser2; // the browser class object

        public void SetSite(object pUnkSite)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(pUnkSite.ToString());
            if (pUnkSite != null)
            {
                m_pIWebBrowser2 = pUnkSite as SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2;
            }
        }

        public void GetSite(ref System.Guid riid, out object ppvSite)
        {            
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("GetSite");
            ppvSite = null;
        }

        protected void DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
        {            
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("DocumentComplete");

        }

        protected bool ServiceEnabled()
        {
            return true;
        }

        protected void Release()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Release");
        }

        protected void BeforeNavigate2(object pDisp, ref object url, ref object Flags, ref object TargetFrameName, 
            ref object PostData, ref object Headers, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("BeforeNavigate2");
        }

        protected void OnQuit() 
        {
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("OnQuit");
            }
            catch{}
        }

        protected void NavigateComplete2(object pDisp, ref object URL)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("NavigationComplete2");            
        }
```

My problem is in my SetSite method, how do i typecast to a browser of any sorts? If i run this sample as it is now, I only get the "GetSite" messagebox, if I remove the if sentence in the SetSite i also get the SetSite. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: if i remove the "if" leaving only the messagebox it shows the messagebox. If i leave the "if" structure there i dont even get the messagebox popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (Non vital to the answer) You really shouldn't be writing a BHO in C#. Yes it can be done, but it isn't a good idea. Even with SxS in .NET 4; the cost of initializing the CLR for every tab opened is pretty high. (If you insist then you should at least be using .NET 4).
2. The Get / Set site methods should return an int according to the documentation for [`IObjectWithSite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Your interface declaration is wrong.
3. Your `GetSite` implementation should look something like this once you get the interface fixed up:

   ```
   public int GetSite(ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvSite)
   {
       var pUnk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(_pUnkSite);
       try
       {
           return Marshal.QueryInterface(pUnk, ref riid, out ppvSite);
       }
       finally
       {
           Marshal.Release(pUnk);
       }
   }
   ```

   In this case, `_pUnkSite` is the object that you were given at `SetSite`. So `SetSite` will look something like this:

   ```
   private object _pUnkSite;
   public int SetSite(object pUnkSite)
   {
       _pUnkSite = pUnkSite;
       //Cast pUnkSite to `IWebBrowser2` here and attach events.
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Once you've finally gotten some of the boilerplate code taken care of, you can cast your `pUnkSite` to something like `IWebBrowser2` to work with the DOM.
4. <shamelessplug>I know that writing a C# BHO is a bad idea [because I have done so](http://vcsjones.com/2009/11/18/writing-a-managed-internet-explorer-extension-part-1-basics/). I have a boilerplate GitHub project [here](https://github.com/vcsjones/IeBHOExamples).</shamelessplug>

Comment: but isnt it SetSite im looking for to typecast into a webbrowser for hooking onto the navigate events. As i read the tuts the GetSite is called after it is loaded for purpose of releasing if needed?

Comment: @H4mm3rHead Your C# interface *needs* to match the COM IDL's definition. .NET will make marshalling mistakes if things don't line up correctly.

Comment: Just changed both of the methods to int, and made the implementation return 0 (zero) - that caused my IExplorer to hang, and nothing replied, before this change i got my messageboxes

Comment: New version: looked through your tut, the one i followed didnt user [PreserveSig] in the interface, now i do and changed the methods to return int, everything works (with return types) and i get my messagebox - still no typecasting yet

Comment: @H4mm3rHead `GetSite` shouldn't return zero. See with my updated code sample.

Comment: Hi, just tried to compile and register your code from github, when i register the assembly it says that it cannot read the assembly because it is not a valid .net assembly. Any ideas?

Comment: Past that now, seems that was a 32/64 bit issue