# Sending HTTP request from BHO

Tags: internet-explorer, com, bho, browser-extension, ieaddon

I want to call the API of my application from an IE extension. I am developing an extension in which the browser extension will call the API whenever a webpage is loaded.

in simple words,
How can i send HTTP request from BHO.

Comment: This isn’t really a question. More details are needed.

Comment: Okay.For eg. I have a icont button on browser window (note:not in web page) just like 'home' & 'Favorite' button. On click of icon button, browser extension will call an API of certain application which is hosted somewhere else on the web and pass some parameters.

Comment: Natives APIs are [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: If you say Native APIs then let me know what is meaning of Native here?

Comment: Native is the opposite to managed. These are Windows core APIs matching your request, those you can use from your [tag:atl] project.

Comment: With the use of WinHTTP, WinINet, i will be able to call an exposed API of application hosted on web?

Comment: With the use of WinHTTP, WinINet, i will be able to call an exposed API of application hosted on web? @RomanR.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting url and HTMl through a BHO, SetSite throws an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040904/getting-url-and-html-through-a-bho-setsite-throws-an-exception)